# JQuery and Wordpress adding active class

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to add an active class to my nav via jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $( '.nav li a' ).each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            });
            $('.nav li a').eq(0).addClass("active");
        </script>
```

I am using wordpress and can see that jquery is defined:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://artendijen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
```

however I am getting this error in my console log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

and the active class is not added to the my nav.

I tried putting this code in header.php and page.php, but gave me the same error above.

Here is my CSS:

```
<div class="navigation">

    <div class="logo">
        <a href="/"><img src="/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/logo.png" width="275" /></a>
    </div><!--logo-->

    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/shop">Gallery & Shopping</a></li>
        <li><a href="/latest-news">Latest News</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/links">Links</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

What Can I do to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: theme probably has `jQuery.noConflict` being used which is likely removing the `$` alias for jQuery. Search your scrip files including local jQuery.js for `noConflict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom of your jQuery.js file that you provided link to is `jQuery.noConflict()` which does remove the `$` alias.

You should be able to get around it by wrapping your code in:

```
/* allows use of `$` in your code*/
(function($){
 /* wait for page to load before running code*/
  $(function(){
      /* your code here */
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Make sure script tag for this code is placed after jQuery.js loads